# OpenOffice install?

Tags: applications

I'm trying to install Open Office. I downloaded and I followed [all the steps appearing in their official site](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux-preinstall) so now it's installed. Now I want to start synapse indicator and when I type 'openoffice' or even 'soffice' I want Open Office to start. I tried to make a desktop file (in /usr/share/applications) to the program directory and it works but it's not recognised by synapse nor the terminal, so how can I make this?

Comment: Just to confirm: Do you really want to use OpenOffice, instead of the feature-full [Libreoffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/)?

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know. I haven't tested with `indicator-synapse` because I am facing [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+bug/1358490)

Comment: Just tested, it can be launched from `indicator-synapse` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**:

First, you have to remove the already installed versions of either openoffice and libreoffice:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice* openoffice*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**Now Install OpenOffice**:

Open terminal and run the following commands to install version 4.1.1 (on 64-bit):

```
wget sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-GB/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
tar -xzvf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
cd en-GB/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
cd desktop-integration
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**To Launch**:

- You can launch from Applications menu:
- From terminal with command: `soffice`

  [image: Imgur]
- You can launch from `indicator-synapse`

  [image: Imgur]

[*Alternately* you can Download from its [official website](https://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html) and install.The download file will be in *.tar.gz format.]

<sub>Reference [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-openoffice-4-1-1-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-debian-8-debian-7-and-derivatives/)</sub>